# Final Integration Testing for Q.A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

A medium sized rails app that our company has been working on is getting close to the end of development and we are going to start doing Q.A. testing on it. We've have been writing unit, functional and integration tests all along and our test coverage is about 99% (even though that really doesn't mean anything).

We feel like we have a pretty good test suite but I was wondering if we should be writing final integration tests for every little action we are going to do during our Q.A. process. If so, would using Shoulda or Cucumber be a good idea? We haven't used either of those testing tools yet, but they sound really great. Any ideas or thoughts would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your integration test suite is sound (meaning that it satisfactorily tests the functionality of all of the interfaces, i.e. how well all of the modules and classes *integrate*), then your next step is functional or acceptance testing.

For functional and acceptance testing there should be a list of requirements.  The functional testing that you perform should prove that the software meets these requirements.  Acceptance testing is typically performed by someone else (the "customer" or "Quality Assurance").